whatsapp integration to voiceflow through whatsapp api
Is there a tool or method available in Meta's support that allows a phone number to be connected to both the WhatsApp Cloud API for automation and the WhatsApp application simultaneously, without deactivating the number from either?
I have tried with flowbridge twilio and so many other channels to solve this problem and still got stuck i am not a developer but yes want to success so can you help me please?

No, you cannot register the same number on both platforms simultaneously.
Read this:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/phone-numbers/

do you know how can i get around it?

No, there's no work around for this. You either register the number on the official API, or use an unofficial api with a regular number.
